# jquery facebox with swf not displaying in ie, displaying in firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, flash, facebox

I have a jquery facebox which contains one swf file. It runs fine in firefox, safari, chrome. But not in any IE version

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because IE limits Ajax access to external domains( address out of your domain ).
If so, you'd better generate content at server side or use IFRAMEs instead.